# Callback for running an external application in C++

Tags: c++, windows, kinect

I'm working on a Kinect v2 application that at some point execute an external Unity mini game that works with Kinect v2 as well. I'm using `ShellExecute` function but I'm not sure how to implement a callback that notify the main application once the Unity application has been closed. I need it because I want to pause the Kinect manager in the main application once Unity is running its own one (otherwise you can imagine two Kinect managers will run at the same time). The code right now looks like:

```
if (Button->getTag() == "something")
{
    Button->SetActive(false);

    // TODO Pause Kinect manager
    ShellExecute(nullptr,L"open",L"UnityApplication.exe",nullptr,nullptr,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

 // TODO to know once Unity Applications has been closed
 // TODO resume Kinect manager
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ShellExecuteEx` instead of `ShellExecute`, passing the flag `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` in the `fMask` field of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure, and then either `WaitForSingleObject` or `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` on the process handle returned in the `hProcess` field of the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure.